# Updating StoreGeneratedPattern.Computed value

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

I have been trying to find a solution to a problem of updating a value of an entity model that is set to StoreGeneratedPattern.Computed but to no success.

The default value of the column [Active] is set in the DB to true. Originally I used StoreGeneratedPattern.Identity but when you update an Identity item you get the error 'Modifying a column with the 'Identity' pattern is not supported.' . I changed to Computed and I'm not getting the error but the value is not updating after I save changes.

Here is my Code:

```
Dim ent As New EntityModel
Dim user As SP_User = (From a In ent.SP_User
                                 Where a.usr_ID = 1
                                 Select a).First

For Each pho As SP_User_PhoneNumber In user.SP_User_PhoneNumber
    Dim foundmatch As u_UserPhoneNumber = Array.Find(PhoneNumers, Function(p As u_UserPhoneNumber) p.PhoneNumberID = pho.usrp_ID)
    If foundmatch Is Nothing Then
        pho.usrp_Active = False
    End If
Next

ent.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: I think you're confusing computed columns and columns with default values. You can't even update computed columns by SQL.

Comment: I agree I do not know much about this and I'm learning as I go along. Do you have a suggestion on how I can make this work?

Comment: Yes, remove the `StoreGeneratedPattern` specification.

Comment: Okey, And then how do I manage the default value in SQL because I have to have a default value generated in SQL

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was setting the StoreGeneratedPattern to none and the Default value to True. The database default value is still set to True(1) thus allowing the database to set the value if an insert is not coming from EF. There might be a loophole to this if the data type is different but in my scenario the solution worked.